# API reponse returns funky format; trying to parse and write to csv

Tags: java

I am using an API to make an HTTP request and I am returning data in the following format:

```
L_TIMESTAMP0=2014%2d08%2d22T05%3a57%3a28Z&L_TIMESTAMP1=2014%2d08%2d22T03%3a25%3a25Z&
```

I normally return data in JSON, but I'm not sure how to parse this exactly. I see that the delimiter is an ampersand.Right now I logging it out in the console and trying to write it out to a csv, but the format is a little funky:

```
System.out.println(response);

try {

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter ("Data.txt", true)));
    printWriter.println (response);
    printWriter.close ();  

}catch (IOException e){

    System.out.println("Failed to write to .csv");

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's basically URL-encoding... try URL-decoding it first and you'll get the values you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is it is returning a url encoded string this is to avoid some issues with passing

So what next try something like this

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(PrintWriter, "UTF-8");
```

tell me how it goes for you

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't change the format. It remains the same for some reason. Also, why is PrintWriter an argument?

Comment: im not that great at java so this is prob wrong.

but i know the string you are getting is url encoded and you need to decode it, so where i have printwriter put in your response and then try it may work

Comment: I'm thinking that "UTF-8" isn't the right encoding. Any thoughts?